jsPDF gives an error: jsPDF.context2d.moveTo: Invalid arguments when using bootstrap btn-close class
In my vue.js application, I have the following code:
let pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "A4");
pdf.html("<button class='btn-close'>hello</button>", {
    width: 170,
    x: 30,
    y: 30,
    callback() {
        pdf.save("questions.pdf");
    }
});
pdf.save("questions.pdf");

However, the btn-close class causes the following error:
jsPDF.context2d.moveTo: Invalid arguments 
Arguments { 0: -99996, 1: NaN, … }
0: -99996
1: NaN
callee: 
length: 2
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): function values()
<get callee()>: function ()
<set callee()>: function ()
<prototype>: Object { … }

I tried removing the btn-close class while keeping everything else the same and it rendered correctly. When this class is present however, it causes the error. This does not happen with the bootstrap classes I use other than btn-close. How can I solve this problem?

Why do you use Bootstrap, to begin with? It does not support Vue3.

@kissu, not if he's using bootstrap 5

@3m1n3nc3 I hope that he is not using BS4 and Vue2, even worse state.

BS4 and Vue2 would be sad as f***
